# cannot find constructor in C++ templated code

Tags: c++, oop, templates, constructor

I am getting this error when compiling it with: g++ main.cpp Vec.cpp -Wall -o main -I.

```
/tmp/cciqbEQJ.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x8b): undefined reference to `Vec<double>::Vec()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x9b): undefined reference to `Vec<double>::~Vec()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

I don't understand because I have done a lot of multiple-source file programs before and I never got this error where the constructor is not found. It seems like the compiler is not  able to dynamically bind the template code to the instantiation of the template. Also, I have put a macro guard on the .h file but it is not shown below.

The source codes are below:

Vec.cpp

```
#include "Vec.h"

using namespace std;

template<class T>
Vec<T>::Vec() {
   create();
}


template<class T>
Vec<T>::Vec( size_type n, const value_type& t ){
        create(n,t);
}
template<class T>
Vec<T>::Vec(const Vec& v)
{
        create(v.begin(), v.end());
}

template<class T>
Vec<T>::~Vec(){
    uncreate();
}

   template<class T>
   void Vec<T>::create()
{
 data = avail = limit = 0;
}

   template<class T>
   void Vec<T>::create(size_type n, const T& val)
{
  data = alloc.allocate(n);
  limit = avail = data + n;
  uninitialized_fill(data,limit, val);
}

template<class T>
void Vec<T>::create(const_iterator i, const_iterator j) {

    data = alloc.allocate(j-i);
    limit = avail = uninitialized_copy(i, j, data);
}
    template<class T> 
    void Vec<T>::uncreate() {

            if (data) {

                    iterator it = avail;
                    while (it != data)
                            alloc.destroy(--it);

                    alloc.deallocate(data,limit-data);
            }
            data = limit = avail =0;
    }

    template<class T> void Vec<T>::grow() {
            size_type new_size = max ( 2 * (limit-data), ptrdiff_t(1));

            iterator new_data = alloc.allocate(new_size);
            iterator new_avail = unitialized_copy(data, avail, new_data);

            uncreate();
            data = new_data;
            avail = new_avail;
            limit = data + new_size;

    }


    template<class T> void Vec<T>::unchecked_append(const T& val) {
            alloc.construct(avail++, val);
    }

    template<class T>
    void Vec<T>::push_back(const T& t){
                    if ( avail == limit )
                            grow();

                    unchecked_append(t);
    }
```

Vec.h

```
    template<class T> class Vec{
    public:
            typedef T* iterator;
            typedef const T* const_iterator;
            typedef size_t size_type;
            typedef T value_type;

            Vec();
            Vec( size_type n, const T& t=T() );

            Vec(const Vec& v);
            Vec& operator=(const Vec& v);

            ~Vec();
            void push_back(const T& t);

            inline size_type size() const { return limit - data; }

            inline iterator begin() {return data;}
            inline const_iterator begin() const { return data; }

            inline iterator end() { return limit; }
            inline const_iterator end() const { return limit; }

            inline T& operator[](size_type i){
                    return data[i];
            }
            const T& operator[](size_type i) const { return data[i]; }


    private:
            iterator data;
            iterator limit;
            iterator avail;

            //facilities for memory allocation
            allocator<T> alloc;

            //allocate and initialize the underlying array
            void create();
            void create(size_type, const T&);
            void create(const_iterator, const_iterator);

            //destroy the elements in the array and free the memory
            void uncreate();

            //support functions for push_back
        void grow();
        void unchecked_append(const T&);
};
```

main.cpp

```
 int main(void) {
   Vec<double> test;
 }
```

Comment: You can't put templates like that in CPP files

Comment: Don't use templates in `*.cpp`.

Comment: Otherwise how is one supposed to define anything in .cpp? Without templates compiler throws "T is undefined"

Answer (score 1):

In order for the compiler to generate the code, it must see both the template definition and the specific types used to for the template.

So, in `main.cpp` add line just `#include "Vec.cpp"` at the **top**.

Compile using 
`g++ main.cpp -Wall -o main -I.`   <-- Notice `Vec.cpp` removed now.

This will make sure the template declaration and implementation are together during compilation, at same time implementation is still separated from declaration.

Another alternative is to include this `.cpp` while at the **end** of `Vec.h` as suggested in the above commented link of SO by juanchopanza

For more details Ref :- [Why can't I separate the definition of my templates class from its declaration and put it inside a .cpp file ?](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates-defn-vs-decl.html)